# syslinux UEFI boot: automatically select boot option based on HW identifier

Tags: boot, uefi, syslinux

I am booting from USB media, and I am using syslinux EFI boot.

I am booting the same media on 2 different laptops, and I have 2 menu options in syslinux.cfg, one for each laptop.

Currently, I have to manually select the right menu option for each laptop.

Is there some way to automate this, and have `syslinux` automatically recognize on which laptop it is booting? Perhaps based on some unique HW identifier?

How could I do this?

this is my `EFI/BOOT/syslinux.cfg`:

```
DEFAULT menu.c32
PROMPT 0
MENU TITLE UEFI boot menu
MENU AUTOBOOT Booting AAA in # seconds

LABEL AAA
MENU LABEL AAA
KERNEL menu.c32
APPEND /AAA/menu

LABEL BBB
MENU LABEL BBB
KERNEL menu.c32
APPEND /BBB/menu
```

the files `/AAA/menu` and `/BBB/menu` then have the correct boot options for each laptop.

so basically, I would need on laptop A, to automatically boot `/AAA/menu`, and on laptop B `/BBB/menu`

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind needing to boot from USB?  Why can you not install 2 copies of `syslinux`, one on each laptop....

Comment: I don't have any experience with syslinux personally. However, could you not install syslinux on each laptop separately and just set different default boot options for each? I.e. it might be easier to give each laptop its own local syslinux and config file, rather than trying to get syslinux to detect the laptop hardware from the USB.

Comment: What is the difference between the two notebooks? I mean, what pieces of hardware information will the decision be made on? Is it possible for you you to share the two sets of boot options?

Comment: I need to boot these laptops from external USB media. I need one master USB media, that works on multiple devices. The devices will have different boot options, such as  different kernel and different boot parameters.

Comment: RE: Different Parameters/Options - If you're going to take that approach, then you need to boot with what's most common between all laptops, i.e like a RescueCD or GParted LiveCD with only one boot choice.  The customized boot menu approach works best only if the menu is installed on the laptop it was customized for.  To make sure I had options in common, if these are your laptops, I would build custom kernels for each laptop from the same config file, and name each kernel the same name.

Comment: I suppose it should be possible to write some COMBOOT module ( https://www.syslinux.org/old/comboot.php inspired from the Hardware Detection Tool unfortunately discontinued since 2015. ( https://github.com/geneC/syslinux/tree/master/com32/hdt )

Comment: Anyway, whatever solution I can think of would need inserting some machine code into the bootloader hence rendering whatever solution architecture dependent, could you please indicate if it is a problem or not and if not, which arch is targeted ?

Comment: @MC68020 thank you for your suggestions. I am using intel and amd laptops, so I guess my architecture is `amd64` ? I don';t need to support any other architecture.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read on arch wiki: [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/syslinux#Chainloading_other_Linux_systems)

I think it is possible, but difficult, using `extlinux` that comes with `syslinux` package, and chain loading twice a syslinux. But I haven't tested it.

And it is a lot of work if you have to do it for more than 2 different computers. Because you will need for 10 different computers, 10 different partitions on the usb drive, each with a copy of the kernel and initrd, as well as some syslinux files.

Each laptop must have the esp boot partition: `/dev/sda1` or at the same `/dev/sdaX`. If no, this method won't work.

Here is the way to proceed:

**1. Install extlinux on laptop A:**

On the laptop A, assuming esp boot partition is /dev/sda1:

```
mkdir ./mntefi
sudo mount /dev/sda1 ./mntefi
sudo mkdir ./mntefi/boot
sudo mkdir ./mntefi/boot/syslinux

# install extlinux:
sudo extlinux -i ./mntefi/boot/syslinux/ 

# copy *.c32 files:
sudo cp /usr/lib/syslinux/bios/*.c32 ./mntefi/boot/syslinux
```

Create a file `./mntefi/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg`

```
TIMEOUT 0

UI menu.c32

LABEL MAIN
    COM32 chain.c32
    APPEND hd1 3
```

This file will chain to the third partition on the usb drive (hd1 if the laptop A have only one internal drive), where there will be the syslinux.cfg for laptop A.

**2. Create partition 3 (/dev/sdb3) on the usb drive:**

The partition can be small, it just have to contain a syslinux and the kernel and initrd.

**3. Install extlinux on partition 3 of the usb drive:**

```
mkdir ./mnt3
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 ./mnt3
sudo mkdir ./mnt3/boot
sudo mkdir ./mnt3/boot/syslinux

# install extlinux:
sudo extlinux -i ./mnt3/boot/syslinux/ 

# copy *.c32 files:
sudo cp /usr/lib/syslinux/bios/*.c32 ./mnt3/boot/syslinux
```

Create a file `./mnt3/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg`

```
DEFAULT menu.c32
PROMPT 0
MENU TITLE UEFI boot menu
MENU AUTOBOOT Booting AAA in # seconds

LABEL AAA
MENU LABEL AAA
KERNEL menu.c32
APPEND /AAA/menu
```

This file will display the menu for laptop A, the menu file is located on partition 3 in the directory `/AAA`.

In the menu file, the kernel must have the following parameters: `root=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx rw`, with the UUID of the partition where the linux is installed on the usb drive.

**4. Main syslinux.cfg, of the usb drive:**

On the usb drive, where the linux system is installed, assuming on partition /dev/sda2, create a file `EFI/BOOT/syslinux.cfg`:

```
TIMEOUT 0

UI menu.c32

LABEL MAIN
    COM32 chain.c32
    APPEND hd0 1
```

This file will chain on the internal drive of the laptop, on the esp boot partition, assuming it is the first partition on the laptop internal drive.

It will always chain the syslinux found on first partition of the internal drive in the laptop.

But maybe syslinux number the drives beginning by the one where it boots, if it does, then it needs to append `hd1 1` instead of `hd0 1`

**5. Repeat the steps 1, 2, and 3, for each laptop.**

Be carefull, that on step 1, the syslinux.cfg must chain to the new partition created on step 2.

Comment: Clever idea indeed and +1 for that. BTW, wouldn't resorting to COM32 restrict this to x86 arches ?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe `COM32` could be replaced by `KERNEL` that seems to be also able to run `.c32` files.

Comment: @Bertrand125 - thank you for the effort. But this will not work. The solution cannot depend on the laptop's boot partition. The whole point in booting from external USB media is to be able to boot the device irrespective what is installed on the HDD, or even if HDD exists (ie booting rescue system). I appreciate your effort, and I will award the bounty anyway, if no better solution is offered. But this will not work for me. Thanks